# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Acer ES 15 Laptop - No bootable device

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, laptop, acer

I was recently given an Acer Aspire ES 15 laptop with windows preinstalled. I tried to wipe windows and do a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 from a pen drive.

The install finished successfully and I restarted the computer but I get the error: "No bootable device". I tried changing the bios settings after reading some q/a's on here. I set a bios security password and booted in UEFI mode with secureboot enabled before reinstalling. Unfortunately, when I then tried to select a "trusted UEFI file" (on HDD0) as suggested in some of the q/a's, there are no files available in the menu.

I have tried installing / booting with secure mode disabled but it makes no difference. I've also tried booting in legacy mode but the screen remains black with a blinking cursor in the top left-hand corner.

The bios version is 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

I had it on a Acer ES1 132
Because it was brand new I returned it to the shop.
BUT you can fix it by changing the bootfile name as the Windows bootfile name.
The UEFI does not allow another bootfile name than Windows.
Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I has Acer Aspire ES 14 laptop. After trials & errors, I found out that in your EFI folder must have "LINUX", not ubuntu, not debian, not lubuntu, not other names. Remember to disable SECURE BOOT in BIOS. So what you need to do are:

1. Bootup using live ubuntu.
2. Use DISK UTILITY to mount your EFI partition.
3. Rename ubuntu folder to LINUX.
4. Go LINUX folder, copy grubx64.efi and paste as another file.
5. Rename that copy as bootx64.efi.
6. In same folder, make sure UUID in *.cfg is refer where your ubuntu partition.
7. Reboot.

Hope it helps.